# App getting hanged while changing orientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, freeze

i know this is going to be a vague question, but please give a thought to this... 
I am developing a book reader on ipad and it has many functionalities like highlight, notes etc. and all these functions are woking well. But the problem comes only when i try to rotate my device after implementing any function.. The app is geting struck(or hanged) after changing itz orientation....

Can anyone tell me why a app usually gets hanged???? Give a thought to this please. Your inputs will help me go a long way.....

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to support both the orientation?

Comment: Have you checked the logs in the Console? It is hanging means it may crash. So you are unable to access that UI. once check the console and tel me what it is showing

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your control frame settings.

If your application support portrait mode alone means code as follows,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

else

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

and change the control frame accordingly.

Comment: hi king and satya.... thanku for your answers. But i am already doing this.... and my app is working fine both in potrait and lanscape...But the problem comes only if u try doing some operations like highlight etc... only then, it gets hanged.. i have seen the console, but i could not even understand a single bit out of it..